How to run SFML 64-bit with a mingw-Compiler including -std=c++23 on Windows?
Conditions of the problem:

Downloaded and unzipped 'SFML (Version 2.5.1)' for 'GCC 7.3.0 MinGW (SEH) - 64-bit' from official website
Copied dll files into my own project folder containing main.cpp which uses SFML
Also copied include and lib folders into the src folder of my project folder
Installed MinGW-w64 via chocolatey (choco install mingw)
Added the bin folder to the environment variables for this account (path)
Compiled project with: g++ -std=c++23 -Wall -Wextra -I src/include *.cpp -o wizard.exe -L src/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

main.cpp:
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Everything looks good up to this point, the compilation works.
How to trigger the error:
When you try to run the program you get the error message that the procedure entry point in a DLL could not be found. This makes the executable file useless.
Question:
How to solve this problem? Unfortunately, the reasons for the error are not explained more detailed.
Approaches already tried:
As a solution, I have already tried reinstalling MinGW via MSYS2. But even with that, the compilation worked, but the execution resulted in the same error.

Just download both MinGW and SFML from MSYS2. You get the latest version of both, and they're guaranteed to be compatible.

After searching and trying for a long time, I was now able to solve the problem myself:
Do not install MinGW via choco install mingw, as this will install a version that is too new (e.g. 14.1.0).
Instead, install an older Version of mingw, e.g. choco install --version 11.1.0
The error occurs due to an incompatibility of the SFML and the mingw versions.
The SFML website recommends using mingw 7.3.0, but the C++ standard std=c++23 is not yet available there.
Through trial and error, I found that the incompatibility starts at 12.x.x, which is why I recommend an 11.x.x version of mingw.
